Getting an error cannot reshape array of size 3034208 into shape (94819,1,28,28)
I try to convert CSV files into image(All images are the 3-D matrix of pixels). So now we re-shape the matrix into a 3-D matrix using this code.
trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
X_train = trainX / 255.0

y_train = train[:,0]


# Reshape and normalize test data
testX = test[:,1:].reshape(test.shape[0],1, 28, 28).astype( 'float32' )
X_test = testX / 255.0

y_test = test[:,0]

But when it run I got this error:
File "E:\rana\untitled2.py", line 18, in <module>
    trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,28, 28).astype( 'float32' )

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3034208 into shape (94819,1,28,28)


Try: train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,8, 4).astype( 'float32' ) or train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],1,16, 2).astype( 'float32' ). print(94819 * 1 * 16 * 2 == 3034208) should be True. print(94819 * 1 * 28 * 28 == 3034208) is False. Same for  testX .
